# When element is not on screen anymore?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my website, there is a floating cloud(element) that scrolls rightwards, and I wanna be able to tell when it's not visible anymore on screen.

How can I do it?

```
setInterval(function(){
    if(!jQuery('.sa_cloud_l').is(':visible')){
        alert('not visible anymore');
    }else{          
        c1.css('left', '+=21');
    }
},100);
```

Comment: Define what is "not visible anymore"?

Comment: compare it's left position with the width of the window.

Answer (score 1):

The `:visible` selector does not account for being inside the viewport of browser.

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document.
>   Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.
>
> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible,
>   since they still consume space in the layout. During animations that
>   hide an element, the element is considered to be visible until the end
>   of the animation. During animations to show an element, the element is
>   considered to be visible at the start at the animation.

Answer (score 1):

Check jquery plugin viewport http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

Comment: Probably the  best approach, all things considered. This is a well-developed plugin.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($(window).scrollLeft() <= $(this).offset().left 
    && $(this).offset().left < $(window).width()+$(window).scrollLeft()
    && $(window).scrollTop() <= $(this).offset().top 
    && $(this).offset().top < $(window).height()+$(window).scrollTop()) {
    // at least part of 'this' is within the window
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`:visible` only selects the elements that their CSS *display* properties are not `none`. You can use `offset()` method.

```
var width = $(window).width();

setInterval(function(){
        if ( $('.sa_cloud_l').offset().left > width ) {
            alert('not visible anymore');
        } else {          
            c1.css('left', '+=21');
        }
},100);
```